# Expo never works

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I am attempting to make my own app with React Native, however it appears as though I'm working harder to get Expo to work more than I am trying to actually debug the app itself. I have tried with LAN, Tunnel, and Local but none of them seems to work. I will get it on some days and it will work fine.. for about 5 minutes and then it will time out or lose connection. Some days though it will just continue to try and load but will never actually pull up the app. I suspect this is because I am using my hotel wifi as well as a vpn (for security on a public network of course). I am wondering if there are any alternatives to expo that I might be able to use because this problem is starting to become very frustrating. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try with expo start --localhost and the smartphone connected to the PC?

Comment: I have not tried this. I unfortunately have an iphone so I don't believe I can debug with React Native through the phone itself but I am using an emulator for android. Would that make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to start Expo in offline mode so that your internet shouldn't be an issue. If you're using yarn the command would be `yarn start --offline`. You may also need to select `Local` once Expo launches.

Source: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/101

Comment: I did not, though that sounds very helpful. I will give it a try. Thanks!

Comment: What would be an alternative to yarn for Windows machines?

Comment: Only options I know of either yarn or npm. Haven’t heard of people using others. I usually switch between npm and yarn depending on the project.